# Passing varying amount of arguments to VBA SubProcedures

Tags: c#, excel, parameters, office-interop, vba

I call a few VBA methods from my C# project.  This has caused me to repeat code in my project. So I created a C# method for the few that take the same amount of parameters but a few take different amounts. So I thought about a solution, all the parameters that I pass in are strings, so what if I pass in to my C# method a string array, then convert that string array in to individual strings in the VBA subprocedure call.  This is what I have:

```
private static void RunVBAMethod(Excel.Application excelApp, string logFile, string vBAMethod, string [] args, out string errorType)
{
     errorType = CSharpError;
     var VbaCrashed = excelApp.Run(vBAMethod, ConvertStringArrayToString(args));
     if (VbaCrashed != "False")
     {
          errorType = VBAError;
          throw new Exception(VbaCrashed);
     }
}
```

Here is my ConvertArrayToString method:

```
private static string ConvertStringArrayToString(string[] array)
{
      // Concatenate all the elements into a StringBuilder.
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (string value in array)
      {
           builder.Append(value);
           builder.Append(',');
      }
      return builder.ToString();
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
RunVBAMethod(excelApp, LogFile, "CleanMRP", new string[] { CurrentWorkbook.TimePeriod, CurrentWorkbook.Version, RemoveSpace(CurrentWorkbook.ReportType), CurrentWorkbook.MainMRPFilePath + CurrentWorkbook.FileName, HeaderRow.ToString(), CurrentWorkbook.DataPath }, out ExcelCrashed);
```

When I run it, it crashes on the excelApp.Run line saying Parameter not optional.  Is, what I am trying to do even possible? Am I looking at the wrong way to do, if it is? or am I missing something so small?